# modify libreoffice writer document from python for auto reporting

Tags: python, python-3.x, reporting, libreoffice-writer

I would like to generate automated reports from my python program. I was using pdf reportlab solution before, but my needs are evolving. I need the possibility to comment / apply modifications in the report.

As a result, I was imagining to create an empty LibreOffice writer document (but with logos, first page, 
etc. like a template), and from my program, I planned to copy this document, feed it from my python prog data, txt and pictures, and save it with a new name.

Like this, the report is closed to be complete and I can adjust it by myself at the end. 
Do you know if it is possible to do that ?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Thx for your help, but when i click on you link i find info on tkinter frame issues. And if you search python libre office writer, you find infos on how to do a macro using uno in the witer file.

Comment: Search [`[python] libreoffice writer`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=isanswered%3Ayes+is%3Aquestion+%5Bpython%5D+libreoffice+writer)

Comment: Thx for your update but it still don't answer...

Comment: ***"still don't answer"***: Search also [`[python] office odt`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=isanswered%3Ayes+is%3Aquestion+%5Bpython%5D+office+odt)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the solution I found is to use python docx library. It can open and save docx like document. It should work with writer docs